# Can debug ticks be read and used in logic bricks?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

When limits are set for a moving part, and debug is enabled, movement is counted by ticks.
Can those ticks from debug be read and used in the logic bricks (probably as a property)?
I want to use an expression in the controller to multiply ticks to get an angle measurement to be used onscreen in my game.
This pertains to my unanswered question: How can an angle be put into a window on-screen on BGE?

Comment: Your frame rate should be constant (default 60fps). The BGE tries to stay within the limit as much as possible. If not it skips up to 4 images to render (but runs physics and logic). Time counting is no good way to measure angles or distances. Better measure the difference to a base state. In your case measure the angle towards the original orientation.

Comment: "Better measure the difference to a base state. In your case measure the angle towards the original orientation."               OK, but how is this accomplished? What is used to measure the angle???

Comment: The BGE uses a matrix (3x3) to calculate the orientation. You can calculate various vectors to determine a direction (e.g. an up-vector or a forward vector). The API provides several functions to work with matrices and vectors (e.g. to calculate the smallest angle between two vectors). See mathutils ->  https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.angle

Comment: @Monster Could you give an example?